# Can Honoree type and name be inserted into the Contribution email receipt?

Tags: tokens, honoree

I feel like this might exist but I can't find it:

What's the best way to insert honoree information in a thank-you letter to a donor? Especially for batch thank you letters.

Comment: I missed your question in my searching but it just came up in "Related" sidebar when I answered my own question. You may be interested in this one: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8402/soft-credit-honoree-info-in-a-token-for-thank-you-letters

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this for honoree info but I have been able to successfully add tokens to the email receipt by pasting the token in the message template in administer - communications -  message templates

Comment: Thanks- stupid question: how did you determine what the token name(s) was for the honoree?