# Soft credit / honoree info in a token for Thank You letters?

Tags: civicontribute, tokens, message-templates, honoree, soft-credit

I have hunted and not found anything so I am assuming that this does not exist -- but thought I'd ask just in case. I'd like to be able to reference the soft credit / honoree information in Thank You letters but can't find this as a token.

I guess it's tricky to do this as a token since it relates to a specific contribution and not the contact in general. What is the best way to try to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt to address this with a token that can be used with Fuzion's [CiviToken](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken) extension. With that extension installed, this token file can be added to a `tokens` directory in your custom PHP folder to provide a "Latest Contrib Soft Credit Name" token. (It checks the latest contribution and if there is a soft credit adds the name(s) in this token). The caveat being that it only checks the latest contribution and won't work for previous contributions.

https://github.com/laryn/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken/blob/master/tokens/latestcontribs.inc

File: **tokens/latestcontribs.inc**

```
<?php

function latestcontribs_civitoken_declare($token){
  return array(
    $token . '.softcredit_name' => 'Latest Contrib Soft Credit Name',
  );
}


function latestcontribs_civitoken_get($cid, &$value, $context){
  $params = array(
    'sequential' => 1,
    'contact_id' => $cid,
    'options' => array('sort' => "receive_date DESC", 'limit' => 1),
  );
  $softcredit_formatted = "";

  $softcredit_name = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'getsingle', $params);

  if (isset($softcredit_name['soft_credit'])) {
    $connector = "";
    $i = 0;
    $total = count($softcredit_name['soft_credit']);
    foreach($softcredit_name['soft_credit'] as $softcredit) {
      $i++;
      $softcredit_formatted .= $connector.$softcredit['contact_name'];
      if ($i == ($total-1) ) {
        $connector = " and ";
      } else {
        $connector = ", ";
      }
    }
  }
  $value['latestcontribs.softcredit_name'] = $softcredit_formatted;
  return $value;
}
```

Comment: For future readers - this token is now built into CiviToken, so you can just install that.